# Modify http headers on system level (Linux)

Tags: linux, http, ubuntu

I want to add http header not just in firefox (using "Modify headers" plugin), but on system level. Since I can't add headers in skype's request, for example, or in IDE's, I need a single point in system to add this header. Is it possible in Linux?

P.S. "Smart" guys who want to close the question: can you put your smart comments?

Comment: Needs a bit more explanation.  "Modify http headers"?  In coming, out going, one particular program, on a third party page, what?

Comment: Only outgoing http headers. I use plugin for firefox, but all other programs can't do this.

Comment: Question makes no sense. Do you want to add headers on the *server* side or just for all client processes on some system?

Comment: I told in the question, that I already use plugin for firefox. Which level it is, how do you think?

Comment: Oh *well*, you use a Firefox plugin, and we're supposed to know which of the approximately 47 billion Firefox plugins you mean?

Comment: and why do you need to know the plugin? the question is not about them

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect all outgoing HTTP requests to a proxy, and have that proxy (e.g. [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) add the headers.

Redirecting all requests to a 80 port (i.e. the default HTTP port) can be done by system-wide `iptables` tricks (but this is disgusting).

Comment: THanks, I had that thought, and how can I add headers using Squid?

Comment: with http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/ICAP and your ICAP server

Answer (score 1):

Using a proxy is really the only way to do this on a system wide basis. Linux has no concept of HTTP headers... it's just there to manage the underlying sockets. Each client program, however, will need to use the proxy.

For Squid, use request_header_replace configuration directive:

```
request_header_replace header_name data
```

Answer (score 0):

i actually just ran into this issue, but there isn't a full simple answer to this question.  a lot depends on which headers you want to remove.  there are some standard http protocol headers which can't be removed on page renders, but to give you some answers to your general question, you should do the following:

ServerSignature Off

ServerTokens Prod

other headers can be removed in your Apache conf file, virtual host definition or your .htaccess file, assuming you're using Apache and you have mod_headers turned on:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset HEADER_NAME
</IfModule>
```

just to reiterate, a lot depends on which headers you want to remove, so if Header unset doesn't work fully, then some of these headers can't be removed without modifications to your apache source or full knowledge of mod_perl to override standard headers.  you can also try to use php, or your code of choice to edit headers, but you may experience some issues with that as well.

i hope this helps, again i just went through this, so i hope to help on some of the challenges and pitfalls, if i can :)

Comment: I just want to add header, nothing needs to be removed

Comment: cool then that's easy, run: `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append HEADER_NAME "VALUE"
</IfModule>` in your conf, vhost or your .htaccess file - good luck

Comment: run where? I'm not using apache. Just client programs. I want single point where I can add header to all outgoing requests

Comment: put that line at the bottom of your httpd.conf and it should work system wide.  sorry i didn't mean run, i meant add these lines :)

Comment: don't forget to restart apache ;)

Comment: I will try tomorrow, thank you for help. I will mark the answer tomorrow.

Comment: @RobertVanSant The OP wants to add a header to the requests of all clients on the system, not to the responses of an HTTP server.

Comment: whoops, sorry i just quickly read add headers.  but this can also be done with SetEnvIf like so `SetEnvIf MyRequestHeader myvalue HAVE_MyRequestHeader
Header set MyHeader "%D %t mytext" env=HAVE_MyRequestHeader`