# How to access client IP of an HTTP request from Google Container Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a gunicorn+flask service in a docker container with Google Container Engine. I set up the cluster following the tutorial at http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/

The `REMOTE_ADDR` environmental variable always contains an internal address in the Kubernetes cluster. What I was looking for is `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` but it's missing from the request headers. Is it possible to configure the service to retain the external client ip in the requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you set up your service by setting the service's type to `LoadBalancer`? It's an unfortunate limitation of the way incoming network-load-balanced packets are routed through Kubernetes right now that the client IP gets lost.

Instead of using the service's `LoadBalancer` type, you could [set up an `Ingress` object](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) to integrate your service with a [Google Cloud HTTP(s) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/), which will add the X-Forwarded-For header to incoming requests.

Comment: Do you know if there are any new solutions for this particular problem?

Answer (score 10):

If anyone gets stuck on this there is a better approach.
You can use the following annotations depending on your kubernetes version:

```
service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

on 1.7

or

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic: OnlyLocal
```

on 1.5-1.6

before this is not supported

source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

note that there are caveats:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#caveats-and-limitations-when-preserving-source-ips