# Modify http headers on system level

Tags: linux, tcp, netfilter

[Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107848/modify-http-headers-on-system-level-linux) can anybody assist? Like using the netfilter. The requirement is addding headers to http/https traffic from which ever browser it comes be it FF or Google chorme. I know we can have plugins service for individual browsers. I would like to have it at system level other than using the plugins. Basically what a plugin does same thing to be done at system level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify http headers on system level (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107848/modify-http-headers-on-system-level-linux)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with *"... can anybody assist?"* This site is not about somebody coming to you and helping you step by step with whatever problem you have. It is about having clear and focused questions and getting clear and focused answers. The question you link to has already several answers, i.e use some proxy and maybe forcibly redirect all traffic to this proxy. If you need more than this information you have to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The answers to the linked or referred question suggests using a proxy server to add an headers to internet traffic. I want to include an http header using a client module which will monitor traffic on real time and include the headers. This client module will run on individual desktop systems. Indvidual internet browsers like firefox or chrome has such plugins but that would only limit to respective browsers.

Comment: Isn't *"client module"* just another name for "I don't know what exactly I will do but it needs to be transparent to the browser"? Or what exactly is this "client module"? And why is a transparent proxy not an option for this? Also note that whatever what you design - it will not be able to modify HTTPS traffic (encrypted) since the encryption is terminated and validated inside the application (browser etc). Or you explicitly need to trust some inspection CA on all the systems, this is what for example antivirus or corporate proxy do.